# Is there a way that I can show my print statements after the user presses a button or enter?

Tags: java

I'm brand new to coding (and stackoverflow), and I am trying to make a choose your own adventure type game. The problem is, when I run the code, it just shows all of my print statements at once, giving me just a huge wall of story text. Is there anyway that I can have the user press a key to activate the next portion of text?

I am currently using a scanner (console.nextInt()) to take the input of the user's decisions. I would like to do the same thing that this does with the text except instead of entering a number, all the user has to do is press enter to reveal the next bit of text.

Comment: Hi Kenneth, show your effort by attaching how you tried to solve to issue you encountered

Comment: The simplest approach...why not just 1) print some stuff, 2) accept some input, 3) print some more stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the scanners `next` method instead (assuming your scanner is listening to `System.in`). This will read the first word (and block your program until there is input) but this can be an empty string as well. Your user can just press enter without typing anything and the program will resume.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd just like it to print whenever you've pressed enter, you can just wait on the input the way you are but make sure your print statements are after the line where you get input.

To take it further you could put your print statements in some form of data structure (even a basic array would work), and loop over the using a `for` loop. You would just put the line where you're getting input at the top of your for loop and the print statement afterwards, using the current index of the loop to pick which statement to show.

This is all considering you print the same statements every time. If you don't, you'll need a more complicated data structure or another solution. Given the problem description this is the best answer I can provide you for now.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> story = new ArrayList<>();
    story.add("This is the first part of the story. Blah blah\n" +
            "blah blah blah blah\n" +
            "blah blah blah blah\n");
    story.add("This is the second part of the story. Blah blah\n" +
            "blah blah blah blah\n" +
            "blah blah blah blah\n");
    story.add("This is more of the story. Blah blah\n" +
            "blah blah blah blah\n" +
            "blah blah blah blah\n");
    story.add("This is yet more of the story. Blah blah\n" +
            "blah blah blah blah\n" +
            "blah blah blah blah\n");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (story.size() != 0) {
        System.out.println(story.remove(0));
        scanner.nextLine();
    }
};
```

Result:

```
This is the first part of the story. Blah blah
blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah

<user hits 'Return' here>
This is the second part of the story. Blah blah
blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah

<user hits 'Return' here>
This is more of the story. Blah blah
blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah

<user hits 'Return' here>
This is yet more of the story. Blah blah
blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah
```

I'd think what you'd really want to do is read each of these blocks out of a file.  You could separate blocks of lines with an empty line, and then when you read the file, break the text up into sections based on reading a blank line.